# Can't center Items properly with css Flex-box and either with "transform: translateZ(-50%)"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center all the "card" - Items inside the "cards"- Container. I tried to use Flex-box with `justify-content: space-around` but the Items weren't centered properly. I also tried to fix that with `transform: translateZ(-50%)` but that didn't work. Actually it didn't change anything.

Can someone please tell me where I have done the mistake?

HTML:

```
            <div class="products">

            <h2 class="products__heading-2 heading-2">Unsere Angebote</h2>

            <div class="cards">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
                        <h4 class="heading-4">Texst</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">TEXT</div>
                </div>

            </div>    
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .products {

    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    grid-column: fullstart-start / fullend-end;

    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba($color-primary, .7),rgba($color-primary, .7)), url(../img/products.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);*/

    

    &__heading-2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }
}

.cards {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    height: 80vh;


    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);*/
    
    


}



.card {
   
    
    perspective: 1500px;
    
    &__side {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
        
        height: 30rem;
        width: 20rem;
        transition: all .9s ease;
        border-radius: 3px;
        
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        
        box-shadow: 0px 1.5rem 4rem 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);


  
        &--front {
            background-color: #f9f7f6;

            &-1 {

            }
        }

        &--back {
            background-color: #f9f7f6;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);

            &-1 {

            }
        }
    }
 

    &:hover &__side--front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    &:hover &__side--back {
        transform: rotateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want them centered then `justify-content: center` is probably what you are looking for...at worst `justify-content: space-evenly` might be an alternative.

Comment: CSS-Tricks has a good guide to [centering items in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)